# Webpage accessing Chrome Extension and using desktopCature

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, video-streaming, html

I am implementing a webpage that simply has a video player that needs to play the stream of the users selected screen.  So far I have implemented the chrome extension to run a Listener on the background.js file.  Then on the webpage.js I send a message to the chrome extension in which the extension then runs the chooseDestopMedia method and allows the user to select which screen to share.  The background.js then returns the corresponding ID to webpage.js via the callback method.  The ID is received properly on webpage.js, but once the webpage.js runs the gotStream method it throws an error.  So far some reason there is a problem receiving the video stream and I am not sure why.  The error that is printed on the console is "NavigatorUserMediaError".  I have attached the code below...

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Class Mate Manifest",
"description": "Extension that allows for user to share their screen",
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 2,

"externally_connectable": {
"matches": [ "https://localhost/PresenterPage/presenterpage.html" ]
},
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
"desktopCapture",
"tabs",
"https://localhost/PresenterPage/presenterpage.html"
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```

webpage.js

```
function gotStream(stream) {
console.log("Received local stream");
var video = document.querySelector("video");
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
localstream = stream;
stream.onended = function() { console.log("Ended"); };
}

function getUserMediaError(err) {
console.log("getUserMedia() failed." + err);
}

function onAccessApproved(id) {
if (!id) {
console.log("Access rejected.");
return;
}


navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
  audio:false,
  video:
  { 
    mandatory: 
    {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop', 
        chromeMediaSourceId: id 
    }
  }
}, gotStream, getUserMediaError);

}
var editorExtensionId = "phdabcobbnbidjflhchajebbldjblmjf";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: "yes"},onAccessApproved);
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log(sender.tab);
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
  ["screen", "window"],
  sender.tab,
  function(id) {
  console.log(id);
    sendResponse({"id": id});
    console.log(id);
  } 
  );
  return true;
}
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the media stream from an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using a content script.  The communication between the website, extension, and content-script is much smoother.

Answer (score 1):

If you had read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-chooseDesktopMedia), you would know that in order for a tab to access the media stream, you need to specify which tab you want to give access to when calling chooseDesktopMedia.

And please for the love of all that is good make sure you validate which tab is asking to see the user's desktop before you let it do that.

*Part 2*:

The reason your new code doesn't work is that all you're doing with the tabs returned by `tabs.query` is logging then. Logging something does not magically make it go into the place in the code where it's supposed to go.

You need to pass the tab received by the callback to chooseDesktopMedia yourself. In practice this means moving most of your code inside the callback (or a separate function).

Plus you need to validate the tab properly for security reasons, I hope you left that out for brevity.

Comment: So I added the tab, but still no luck.

Comment: So I have updated the code once again with a much easier way for passing in the tab.  Also I do not know what you mean by validate the tab properly.  Could you please explain?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: And does that work? What I mean by validating the tab is what you're doing now is essentially let any website on the internet communicate with your extension. You should make sure it's your specific website before you allow the entire internet access to the user's desktop (it does show a prompt the first time, but does it have a "Don't ask again" button?)

Comment: Does calling `webkitGetUserMedia` directly in the extension instead of a webpage help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do SO chat.

Comment: So you are saying to call webkitGetUserMedia in the extension then somehow send the stream to the page?

Comment: No, I was talking about a temporary test to see if it works even within the extension, to rule out security restrictions.

Comment: Yes I have implemented the desktop capture in the extension itself.  I had the video playing in the pop up from the extension.  I have also had it working in a chrome app.  I am just having trouble with an external page.  I am using local host for my webpage, but i'm not sure if that would effect anything.